# QGIS - import *.dsf files (Danish National Format)

Tags: qgis, dsfl

I'm new to QGIS and in way above my head with the quest at hand. I'm trying to create a 3D map of a Danish city, to this task the Danish municipality has provided a map of the area the so called KORT10 which I would like to import into QGIS, the map consist of four parts which all is DSF files, it should be vector format, but when trying to add vector layer it pops up with an error saying:

```
"Invalid Data Source C:\Users\.........\KORT10.dsf is not a valid or recognized data source".
```

I have heard some talk about it being Shapefiles or something like that, but as mentioned this is the very first time using QGIS and GIS in general.

I have uploaded the file from the municipality if what I have just described made absolutely no sense but somebody has an interest in helping me. The CRS system used is "EPSG2583/ETRS89"

http://www.filedropper.com/510dsflutm32-euref891

I hope somebody has the time and knowledge to help me.

Comment: You may ask this at the qgis user mailing list too. There are some contributors from Denmark. According to https://www.lifa.dk/arcgis, conversion should be possible with Arcgis too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice download, 80Mb zipfile, but anyway. Some gXXgling reveals that your .dsf files represent an example for the 'Danish National Format' **dsfl**, wich is a text format, but not xml.

Unfortunatly I think that this is one of the few formats not directly readably with qgis, or gdal, rsp.

I succeeded in opening your files (KORT10) with FME (https://www.safe.com/fme/format-search/danish-dsfl/index.php), where a dsf reader/writer is implemented (cp. screenshots below). With FME you can convert these files in any format you need. Since this is a commercial tool, you either know someone with an ASP license, who can convert these files for you, or you get a FME trial version from https://www.safe.com/fme/fme-desktop/trial-download/. If you need help with the conversion, don't hesitate to ask.

FME Workspace
[image]

Part of KORT10 in FME Data Inspector
[image]

Update/Add:

The simplest way to achieve a "1:1" conversion ist to start FME Workbench and then select 'Generate Workspace...'. Select your dsf file as Reader and ESRI shp as Writer (select the target folder), leave coordinate system as 'Read from source/Same as Source':

[image]

The workspace should look like something shown below (note that while running you can see the features count up):

[image]

[Hint: for these selected KORT10.dsf file the resulting shapes will be ~364Mb, so if not all attributes are needed, it might make sense to put an AttributeKeeper transformer in between]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have imported the data into FME, run translation, but then what? I can see that you have the exact map I need in the Data inspector, but need to export it to Qgis, any ideas. Sorry for the lack knowlage, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll add some screenshots to my answer. For basic use of FME I suggest youtube (search for fme basics).

Answer (score 2):

Not come across this format before. It seems to be either a Vector drawing format or a [3D mesh format used in X-Plane](http://developer.x-plane.com/?article=dsf-file-format-specification) (a flight sim).

It might be worth looking at [OpenGeoXPlane](https://opengeoxplane.net/) if it's the latter, they have various tools on there which might be able to help.

Also, at the foot of the Vector import file types combo I see there's an option for **X-Plane/Flightgear** (in QGIS 2.16 at least) although it doesn't seem to pick up .dsf files

Answer (score 2):

Instead of choosing a whole municipality you can "Tegn et område" (draw an area) and woopti you can choose other data formats including .shp. I have no idea why it is like this.

[Direct link](https://download.kortforsyningen.dk/content/kort10-vektor) to download of Kort10 data

Answer (score 0):

The really easy way of doing it is just to choose to download a region or the entire country. Then you'll get in either ESRI Shape or MapInfo format, it's apparently only the municipalities that comes in DSFL. The ESRI and MapInfo files are also newer than the DSFL.